# Twitter and facebook login from android app programmatically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

Can I make an authenticate and login for Twitter and Facebook from my android app programmatically
But I don't want to use any library that warp it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following libraries for that

[Facebook Lib](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

[Twitter Lib](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)

Comment: can i just use httppost with some params?